# What is the namespace for StatementCollections in CodeIt.Right?

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I am creating a custom rule in `CodeIt.Right`. I am trying to get the list of statements using [RuleUtilities.GetMethodStatements](http://submain.com/codeit.right/sdk/SubMain.CodeItRight.Sdk.Utils.RuleUtilities.GetMethodStatements.html) method. This method returns StatementCollection object but visualstudio 2010 and 2013 are unable to find this class. Which namespace or class should be used to store Collection of Statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add reference in your project to SubMain.CodeItRight.CodeObjectModel.dll (you will find it in the %PROGRAMFILES%\SubMain\CodeIt.Right \ folder) in order to use StatementCollection.

For some examples please see [CodeIt.Right - Creating Custom Rules](http://community.submain.com/blogs/tutorials/archive/2008/03/16/tutorial-creating-custom-rules.aspx) and [CodeIt.Right - Extending Existing Rules](http://community.submain.com/blogs/tutorials/archive/2009/10/29/tutorial-extending-existing-rules.aspx)

Thanks!